# Sorting by name part of the columns in a data frame without changing the position of the other columns in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, multiple-columns

I have a data frame with 906 columns. 160 columns are names of world languages. So, the data frame columns are more or less like this:

```
[c1,c2,c3,c4,c....,Italian, English, German, French, Albanian, Spanish,... c903, c904, c905, c906]
```

I know how to sort the columns, but considering all of the columns of the data frame, not only part of it. How can I sort alphabetically in Python only the columns with the names of the languages without changing the order of the other columns?
My desired output should look like this:

```
[c1,c2,c3,c4,c....,Albanian, English, French, German, Italian, Spanish,... c903, c904, c905, c906]
```

Many thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: are all the other columns in the form "c+digits"?

Comment: No, the name of the other columns are completely different from each other

Comment: OK, but you can identify which ones are the country names and which ones are not?

Comment: Yes, I can because they are named by country language

Comment: OK, then just use that instead of my regex to create the boolean array and apply the `cumsum` on it (see my answer). [langcodes](https://pypi.org/project/langcodes/) might be useful ;)

Comment: @FabianoRuggeri Are the language names starting with capital letters and others not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming all your non countries columns can be identified and converted to a boolean (here using a regex to match `c\d+`, bus this could be anything), you can use [`numpy.lexsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html):

```
# identify non-target columns
# the regex here is just an example
# any other method can be used
a = df.columns.str.fullmatch('c\d+')
# array([ True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False,
#        False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True])

# compute a first sorter with a custom cumsum
# the odd numbers are the original True
pos = (2*a).cumsum()-a
# array([ 1,  3,  5,  7,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  9, 11, 13, 15])

# sort by first sorter then column names
df2 = df.iloc[:, np.lexsort((df.columns, pos))]
```

To get the languages columns from a list of valid languages, it is possible to use [`langcodes`](https://pypi.org/project/langcodes/):

```
from langcodes import language_lists

lang = language_lists.WIKT_LANGUAGE_NAMES['en']

a = ~df.columns.isin(lang)
# array([ True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False,
#        False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True])

pos = (2*a).cumsum()-a
df2 = df.iloc[:, np.lexsort((df.columns, pos))]
```

output:

```
['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'Albanian', 'English', 'French', 'German',
       'Italian', 'Spanish', 'c903', 'c904', 'c905', 'c906']
```

used input:

```
cols = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'Italian', 'English', 'German',
        'French', 'Albanian', 'Spanish', 'c903', 'c904', 'c905', 'c906']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think that only works if the other columns are C+digit which is not the case.

Comment: @FabianoRuggeri precisely not, this work with anything as long as your can generate an array `a` in the form `np.array([True, False, True, ...])` where each True is a non-language column. Then run `pos = a.cumsum()` and the rest of my code.

Comment: @mozway I suggest including that comment in the answer!

Comment: @Stef yes I think this is necessary, I updated ;)

Comment: I added a way to detect the language columns

Comment: @mozway I'm unearthing a mummy but can you tell why the column `c4` has been moved after the _lexsort/iloc_ ? Is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: @Timeless and you were right thanks! There was a mistake. The `cumsum` was grouping the col4 with the subsequent country columns. I fixed it by changing the `cumsum` logic (sum the double, then remove original)